# Read file with Javascript Fetch API without knowing the name of the file

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a directory of text files called `./text-files`. I can read files using the fetch API like this:

```
fetch('./text-files/foo.txt')
  then(res => {
    return res.text()
  })
  .then(text => {
    console.log(text)
  })
```

Does the fetch API support some way to read a directory of files without knowing the specific name of the files only the file extension?

Ideally, I'd like some way to get a list of all files in the directory `./text-files` and then read each one serially using fetch. Is this possible? If it's possible to read one file off disk in Javascript, I would think there'd be some way to get a list of file and read each of them?

I was trying to do something like this, which didn't work:

```
fetch('./text-files/*.txt')
  then(res => {
    return res.text()
  })
  .then(text => {
    console.log(text)
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible assuming that you are attempting to read all files from a remote server directory while only using fetch. You can make an API endpoint on remote machine that will return an array of files. That remote API endpoint can use Node's `fs` module and something along the lines of:

```
fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
console.log(items);

for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i]);
}});
```

Then once you fetched an array of files you can then set up them to be individually be fetched using `fetch` api.

Comment: Thanks. Files are all local. If I can read one file successfully (which I can). Why can't I read all of them in a directory?

Comment: @turtle because you are sandboxed in the browser. You can request a specific file and if permissions allow it you will get that file. Listing the contents of a directory is an entirely different thing. You will not be able to do this on a local machine, the browser will not give you access to the information as it is a huge security hole. Just think, you wouldn't want some random site to be able to access the list of all the files on your C:\ drive now would ya

Comment: @http `fetch()` uses the HTTP protocol, which doesn't have any directory listing operations.

Comment: @AdamH: Thanks. Yes, what you're saying makes sense I guess. I would think reading a file from disk even if you know its name is also a big security hole. Someone could even try guessing the names of important files. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Hey @turtle you are right but because the page you are loading is a local resource the browser is giving you special permissions, the second you pull that page via http(s):/ instead of file:/ it will block it